# How can I use && with my own functions?

Tags: bash

Running this prints out both statements

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello" && echo "World"
```

However, running this only prints out "Hello"

```
#!/bin/bash
message() {
  echo "Hello"
  return 1
}
message && echo "World"
```

Why doesn't this work and how can I change my script so that it does?

Comment: There should be a badge for triggering N simultaneous identical answers.

Comment: As the answers below all state, `bash` uses the inverse values for success/failure to your usual true/false expectations, due to being based on return codes.

Comment: @Ben I actually got 2 more but they were deleted :)

Comment: See http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash -- `&&` and `||` are Control Operators and should not be confused with boolean short-circuit logic operators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An "exit" value of 0 means success while anything else means failure. and the && operator doesn't execute the right hand side if the left hand side fails (that is if it returns non-zero)

So change the `return 1` to `return 0`

Comment: 0 means true? I should have guessed :). Thanks!

Comment: @Rupert Not "true or false" -- rather: `a && b` means "run b only if a succeeded" -- note there is no attachment of "true or false" here because, while `&&` and `||` resemble boolean short-circuit evaluators, they are not. They are "Control Operators".

Answer (score 6):

`return 1` (or anything else which is not 0) means `false` to bash, which means the second command will not be called.

Use `return 0` (this means `true`), or chain them using other operators (like `||` or `;`.)

<sub>As mentioned in a comment, technically bash doesn't have boolean values, and `&&` and `||` are not described as "boolean short-circuit operators" in the manual, but "control operators". As `a && b` means "run `b` if and only if `a` succeeded", and "success" is defined as a zero exit code (and the command `true` always returns 0, while `false` returns 1), the net effect is the same as what I described above.</sub>

Comment: This is not necessarily true. `&&` and `||` are not boolean short-circuit operators (and thus the standard TTL logic or names does not apply). They are Control Operators where `a && b` means "run b only if a succeeded" (there is no "true or false") -- From the manual: "command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero."

Comment: @pst: Yeah, and what are the exit statuses of the commands `true` and `false`?  `&&` and `||` work in bash just like boolean short cut operators, if we know "exit code = 0 means true, anything else means false".

Answer (score 5):

In bash a return value of `1` indicates an error.

Try `return 0`

Answer (score 4):

&& executes the second instruction only if the first one is successful, i.e. has a 0 result

Answer (score 1):

Remove the return statement in your `message()` function.

Comment: It is useful to know that the default return evaluates to true so thanks. This won't help in all situations though.